# Camera Lerp seems to be incrementing every loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 7 positions I would like to iterate between and they all have a difference on the x axis of 4.5 so Position0 = 0, Position1 = 4.5 & Position = 9, so on and so forth.

However, it appears that when I go from Position0 to Position1, x continues to grow by 4.5. The iterate through the array works but it just increases by 4.5 every frame. What am I doing wrong?

```
    void Start () {
 _positionArray[0] = position0;
 _positionArray[1] = position1;
 _positionArray[2] = position2;
 _positionArray[3] = position3;
 _positionArray[4] = position4;
 _positionArray[5] = position5;
 _positionArray[6] = position6;
 endPosition = position0;
}

public void changeDestination() 
{
if (_leapManager.swipePerformed)
{
  swipeDirection = _leapManager.swipeDirection;
  if (swipeDirection == "left" && posInArray >= 0 && posInArray < 5)
  {
    Debug.Log("called");
    posInArray++;
    endPosition.position = _positionArray[posInArray].position;
  }
  else if (swipeDirection == "right" && posInArray <= 5 && posInArray > 0)
  {
    posInArray--;
    endPosition.position = _positionArray[posInArray].position;
  }
}
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, endPosition.position, speed * 3.0f * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: You could try clamping the movement by making a basic clamp function(this is just something I used to do with all lerps in unity due to the floating point inaccuracy)

Comment: Also why are you using delta time in your journey fraction area?

Comment: I'm using deltaTime to get a smoothing fast to slower effect on the Lerp. Yeah I might try that but I just wanted to know why it kept increasing by the position axis rather than become it.

Comment: Most likely the fraction will exceed 1 'speed * 3.0f * Time.deltaTime > 1'